# WPF Binding and unhandled exceptions

Tags: wpf, exception, binding

I am binding images to URLs. If the image does not exist, is just now shown, and I see a System.Net.WebException thrown into the output window. That's what I need, if not there, don't show, but my question is: are these unhandled exceptions going to create any other issues? (performance,etc)

Answer (score 0):

Good question. 
Actually there is no issue if you don't catch an exception, if you're sure that it won't cause the application to crash.

Normally the flow of the application is affected by exceptions and chances are there to get the application crashed. So it's the normal process to catch exceptions and handle them. You could either show a message or some default image in a case where there is no exception.

Also try below code for handling unhandled exceptions.

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException
    += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(ErrorHandler.HandleException);`

Comment: I'm just starting the application, so I don't know if it will crash, that's why I wanted to ask :). If not, I wouldn't need to handle the exception. What I need is to show up to 4 images for a product, but if they don't exist, don't show, so current behavior is fine

Comment: Yea. I just suggested it. I did not tell to display 4 images. I told if there is no image you could use a default image or something. It's just my opinion. You could consider it or not :) And handling the exceptions is the best practice to do, unless you're the only one who is gonna use it.